# android webview displaying only partial webpage content

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview, android-maps

I am writing a program that will encompass many thing but one being an interactive campus wide map.  Rather than rewriting the mapview for custom purposes and keeping in mind this style map is common for college campus's I've found webview to be nearly perfect to my plan of attack.

```
final WebView myMapWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mapWebView);
myMapWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myMapWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient(){
});
myMapWebView.loadUrl("http://campusmaps.umn.edu/tc/campusviewer.html");
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This displays the loading bar the webpage shows as well, the header from the webpage (albeit scrunched) their navigation, compass, map location or what ever is at the bottom right of the map, and the radio buttons for map style but no map.  Anyone have any ideas on why this map is not loading into the webview?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the Mapping API the map is made with that is not compatible with android -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your settings in `layout.xml` and make sure both the `WebView` and its parent layout have `match_parent` set under `layout_height` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:scrollbarSize="20px">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <WebView android:id="@+id/appView" 
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```